# Diversity Index - Vegan Package

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to calculate the Simpson's Diversity Index, and I am wondering if I can keep the row names using the vegan package.

My dataset currently looks something like this:

```
           hab   Sp1   Sp2
1     habitat1   1645  1550
2     habitat2   2935  3060
3     habitat3   4780  2875
4     habitat4   3370  3500
5     habitat5   3730  2270
6     habitat6   2475  1140
7     habitat7   1405  1160
8     habitat8   6180  4145
9     habitat9    795   140
10    habitat10  4745  4595
```

The code I am using is:

```
data_simp %>% 
  diversity("simp")

Error in diversity(., "simp") : input data must be numeric
```

I managed to get the Simpson's indices for each row when I deleted the first column in my dataset. However, I would like to keep the first column to create a new dataset with the name of the 'habitat' and the correspondent Simpson's Diversity Index.

Is it possible?

Thank you :)

Comment: better use  `dput(head(df)` that will be helpful as it looks like "simp" data is not numeric it might be character or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wq1SXGQYgCs) on Youtube, I found the answer to my question.

I managed to run the index using the wide format of the dataset, instead of the long format.

```
           hab   value  Sp
1     habitat1   1645  Sp1
2     habitat1   1550  Sp2
3     habitat2   2935  Sp1
4     habitat2   3060  Sp2
4     habitat3   4780  Sp1
5     habitat3   2875  Sp2
```

The code:

```
data_simp %>% 
  group_by(hab) %>% 
  summarise(simpson = simpson(value))
```

The result:

```
   hab              simpson
   <chr>            <dbl>
 1 habitat1          0.500
 2 habitat2          0.500
 3 habitat3          0.469
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you cannot keep them separate and merge back in? For example:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  hab = paste0("habitat", 1:10),
  Sp1 = c(1645, 2935, 4780, 3370, 3730, 2475, 1405, 6180, 795, 4745),
  Sp2 = c(1550, 3060, 2875, 3500, 2270, 1140, 1160, 4145, 140, 4595)
)

data_simp <- cbind.data.frame(df$hab, vegan::diversity(df[,2:3]))
#> 1  habitat1  0.6927051
#> 2  habitat2  0.6929298
#> 3  habitat3  0.6618545
#> ...
```

(you might want to add more informative column names after this step)

Comment: I am running the same index for 10 datasets so that I would have 10 different sets of Simpson's indices. Some of the datasets do not have the same 'habitat'.

Comment: @Alice that's not the question you asked, though you can easily extend this logic to apply to each dataset individually & then bring together the results again. It's not an option to provide character input to `vegan::diversity` (or any other input that's not relevant to the calculation).

Comment: Sorry, thank you for replying. I was just trying to explain why I couldn't keep them separately and merge them back in later :)